# Multiple Like clauses Order by most match contains

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have an AreaMaster Table

[image]

If I search "AreaName" Like '%New Kant%'
it should return  Most match value (First record in row)

**Suppose**

If I search "Sector 26 Navi" It should return last record in table

If I search " Sector 45 400706" It should return 4th record from table and the last one which contain sector word

Comment: Look up full text search.  Regular SQL is not suitable for this type of operation.

Comment: Do you mean to find each word?

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: The closest thing SQL Server has to something like this is `SOUNDEX` and `DIFFERENCE` (and to a lesser extent `PATINDEX`), but these rarely get you what you want, let alone efficiently. Per Gordon, use either SQL Server's own full text search, or something custom entirely like Lucene.

Comment: Thanks, Jeroen Mostert  I already searched for SOUNDEX  and DIFFERENCE. Can you provide a little bit information about full-text search @GordonLinoff although I'm going to search on the internet

Comment: Yes right @McNets

Comment: Full text search https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I don't have any SQL Server around (and the Full Text is not enable on Online SQL-Server test tool), I can't try my code.

```
CREATE TABLE t
    ([id] int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, [first_name] varchar(9), [address] varchar(21))
;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UIX_SomeUniqueIdex ON dbo.t(ID);
;

/*Create a Catalog*/
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG Test_Catalog AS DEFAULT;
;

/* Finally the FTS Index */
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON t (address) 
   KEY INDEX UIX_SomeUniqueIdex;
;


INSERT INTO t
    ([id], [first_name], [address])
VALUES
    (1, 'Aura', '2 Clarendon Way'),
    (2, 'Horacio', '2503 Hazelcrest Court'),
    (3, 'Siana', '68 Emmet Trail'),
    (4, 'Lief', '86853 Mesta Plaza'),
    (5, 'Alvinia', '1 Fieldstone Street'),
    (6, 'Joela', '737 3rd Circle'),
    (7, 'Elwin', '1 Oakridge Point'),
    (8, 'Nell', '137 Hoffman Crossing'),
    (9, 'Julie', '438 Magdeline Avenue'),
    (10, 'Abdel', '237 Jackson Hill'),
    (11, 'Phylys', '83 Claremont Street'),
    (12, 'Ignacius', '4629 Canary Hill'),
    (13, 'Emmery', '26 Carey Terrace'),
    (14, 'Darrel', '04 Namekagon Pass'),
    (15, 'Batsheva', '9021 Hermina Parkway'),
    (16, 'Constance', '60 Bluestem Junction'),
    (17, 'Wes', '49416 Carey Hill'),
    (18, 'Gilda', '7515 Grover Circle'),
    (19, 'Nari', '6 Brentwood Junction'),
    (20, 'Fabiano', '7216 Artisan Place')
;
```

The select:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE FREETEXT(address, '1 Place');
```

Comment: The answer is perfectly working in your scenario but if I'm checking with a large number of data it does not shows most matching contain on top although thank you. Today I learn a new query which I had never used in my whole life `FULLTEXT` @Blag

Comment: @abhi you can change the config of FTS to match you case, but usually most common words are dropped (if it bring the whole DB, what the point?), There is other mode that FREETEXT, take a look, it may be what you're after...

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
DECLARE @MyWord NVARCHAR(50) = 'ABC EFG'
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    Qstn NVARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES
('ABC EFG'),
('HIJ ABC'),
('XYZ KHJ'),
('HIJ DAS')

;WITH PTN
AS
(
    SELECT
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Qstn),
       FullWord = Qstn,
       Qstn = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(Qstn,CHARINDEX(' ',Qstn),LEN(Qstn)))),
       SpInd = CHARINDEX(' ',Qstn),
       MyWord = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Qstn,1,CHARINDEX(' ',Qstn)))),
       WordSpot = 1,
       SpcCnt = LEN(Qstn)-LEN(REPLACE(Qstn,' ',''))
       FROM @T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
       RN,
       FullWord,
       Qstn = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(Qstn,CHARINDEX(' ',Qstn),LEN(Qstn)))),
       SpInd = CHARINDEX(' ',Qstn),
       MyWord = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Qstn,1,SpInd))),
       WordSpot = WordSpot+1,
       SpcCnt = SpcCnt-1
       FROM PTN
          WHERE SpcCnt > 0

),HIT
AS
(
    SELECT
       T1.RN,
       HITRN = COALESCE(Q.RN,T1.RN)
       FROM PTN T1
          OUTER APPLY
          (
             SELECT
                T2.RN
                FROM PTN T2
                    WHERE T1.RN <> T2.RN
                       AND CHARINDEX(T1.MyWord,T2.MyWord)>0
          )Q
),RST
AS
(
SELECT
    SeqNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY S.FullWord,M.FullWord ORDER BY S.FullWord),
    Original = S.FullWord,
    PatternMatch = M.FullWord    
    FROM HIT
       INNER JOIN PTN M
          ON HIT.RN = M.RN
       INNER JOIN PTN S
          ON HIT.HITRN = S.RN
             and S.FullWord = @MyWord
)
SELECT
    *
    FROM RST
       WHERE SeqNo = 1
```

Comment: Way too complicate answer, you should show how to use full text search instead...

Comment: Agree with @Blag

Comment: This was the quickest answer I could think of.

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh ok, I'll make the FULL TEXT one, you'll understand why I think this one is way to complex XD